# How to insert the content of a org-mode's code block inside <pre><code> tags when exporting to HTML?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

When exporting to HTML, org-mode renders a code block in a very ugly way, I don't like that. I want to use [HighlightJs](https://highlightjs.org/) to highlight my exported code blocks. But, **how do I tell org-mode to simply insert the content of the code block and wrap it around `<pre><code>` tags when exporting to HTML?** adding the language name to `<code>` as a class would be great.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a configuration for that. Looks like you'll have to advise `org-html-src-block`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

see https://github.com/redguardtoo/org2nikola/blob/master/org2nikola.el

I simplify it a little bit. Now you just run `org2html-export-subtree` anywhere at the first level node, the  content of the node will be output into a html file whose name is normalized from the node's title.

or you just `C-c C-e` which is handled by `org2html-wrap-blocks-in-code`

The original code is borrowed from org2blog, it supports org7 and org8. It's pretty stable.

Here is the complete code. **It's exactly designed for highlight.js**! I've been using it for many months. See http://blog.binchen.org for samples.

```
(defun org2html-trim-string (string)
  (replace-regexp-in-string "\\`[ \t\n]*" "" (replace-regexp-in-string "[ \t\n]*\\'" "" string)))

(defun org2html--char-to-string (ch)
  (let ((chspc 32)
        (chsq 39)
        (ch0 48)
        (ch9 57)
        (cha 97)
        (chz 122)
        (chA 65)
        (chZ 90)
        (chdot 46)
        (chminus 45)
        (chunderscore 95)
        rlt)
    (cond
     ((or (and (<= ch0 ch) (<= ch ch9))
          (and (<= cha ch) (<= ch chz))
          (and (<= chA ch) (<= ch chZ))
          (= chunderscore ch)
          (= chminus ch)
          )
      (setq rlt (char-to-string ch)))
     ((or (= chspc ch) (= chsq ch) (= chdot ch))
      (setq rlt "-")))
    rlt
    ))

(defun org2html-get-slug (str)
  (let (slug )
    (setq slug (mapconcat 'org2html--char-to-string str ""))
    ;; clean slug a little bit
    (setq slug (replace-regexp-in-string "\-\-+" "-" slug))
    (setq slug (replace-regexp-in-string "^\-+" "" slug))
    (setq slug (replace-regexp-in-string "\-+$" "" slug))
    (setq slug (org2html-trim-string slug))
    (setq slug (downcase slug))
    slug))

(defun org2html-replace-pre (html)
  "Replace pre blocks with sourcecode shortcode blocks.
shamelessly copied from org2blog/wp-replace-pre()"
  (save-excursion
    (let (pos code lang info params header code-start code-end html-attrs pre-class)
      (with-temp-buffer
        (insert html)
        (goto-char (point-min))
        (save-match-data
          (while (re-search-forward "<pre\\(.*?\\)>" nil t 1)

            ;; When the codeblock is a src_block
            (unless
                (save-match-data
                  (setq pre-class (match-string-no-properties 1))
                  (string-match "example" pre-class))
              ;; Replace the <pre...> text
              (setq lang (replace-regexp-in-string ".*src-\\([a-zA-Z0-9]+\\).*" "\\1" pre-class)  )

              (replace-match "")
              (setq code-start (point))

              ;; Go to end of code and remove </pre>
              (re-search-forward "</pre.*?>" nil t 1)
              (replace-match "")
              (setq code-end (point))
              (setq code (buffer-substring-no-properties code-start code-end))

              ;; Delete the code
              (delete-region code-start code-end)
              ;; Stripping out all the code highlighting done by htmlize
              (setq code (replace-regexp-in-string "<.*?>" "" code))

              ;; default is highlight.js, it's the best!
              (insert (concat "\n<pre><code class=\"lang-"
                              lang
                              "\">\n"
                              code
                              "</code></pre>\n"))

              )))

        ;; Get the new html!
        (setq html (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-min) (point-max))))
      ))
  html)

(defun org2html--render-subtree ()
  "Render current subtree"
  (let ((org-directory default-directory)
         html-file
         tags
         title
         post-slug
         html-text)

    ;; set title
    (setq title (nth 4 (org-heading-components)))

    ;; set POST_SLUG if its does not exist
    (setq post-slug (org2html-get-slug title))
    ;; html file
    (setq html-file (concat (file-name-as-directory default-directory) post-slug ".html"))
    (setq html-text (org2html-export-into-html-text))

    (save-excursion
      (setq html-text (org2html-replace-pre html-text)))

    (with-temp-file html-file
      (insert html-text))
    (message "%s created" html-file)
    ))

(defun org2html-export-into-html-text ()
  (let (html-text b e)

    (save-excursion
      (org-mark-element)
      (forward-line) ;; donot export title
      (setq b (region-beginning))
      (setq e (region-end))
      )

    ;; org-export-as will detect active region and narrow to the region
    (save-excursion
      (setq html-text
            (cond
             ((version-list-< (version-to-list (org-version)) '(8 0 0))
              (if (fboundp 'org-export-region-as-html)
                  (org-export-region-as-html b e t 'string)))
             (t
              (if (fboundp 'org-export-as)
                  (org-export-as 'html t nil t)))
             )))
    html-text))

(defun org2html-export-subtree ()
  "Export current first level subtree into HTML"
  (interactive)
  (let ((org-directory default-directory)
        html-file
        tags
        title
        post-slug
        html-text)

    ;; just goto the root element
    (condition-case nil
        (outline-up-heading 8)
      (error
       (message "at the beginning ...")))

    ;; should be nil
    (org2html--render-subtree)
    ))


(defun org2html-wrap-blocks-in-code (src backend info)
  (if (org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'html)
      (org2html-replace-pre src)))

(eval-after-load 'ox
  '(progn
     (add-to-list 'org-export-filter-src-block-functions
                  'org2html-wrap-blocks-in-code)
     ))
```

Comment: My only concern was the external functions, and the possible external function inside those external functions, how much work will cost to adapt this code snippet for my needs?

Comment: I updated original code, there is no dependency now. all you need is copy/paste.

Comment: copying and pasting this elisp code makes me feel like a Script kiddie, ha! I really need to domain Emacs lisp!. Thank you!

Comment: Also, I was using this `(add-to-list 'org-export-filter-src-block-functions 'shackra:org-html-wrap-blocks-in-code)` as in the @rasmus' answer. I wonder if is possible to *connect* the correct function on your code snippet (I wonder if it is `org2html-replace-pre`) to `org-export-filter-src-block-functions`! and should I keep or delete the `(setq org-html-htmlize-output-type nil)` statement?

Comment: I updated code.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe something like this:

```
(defun rasmus/org-html-wrap-blocks-in-code (src backend info)
  "Wrap a source block in <pre><code class=\"lang\">.</code></pre>"
  (when (org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'html)
    (replace-regexp-in-string
     "\\(</pre>\\)" "</code>\n\\1"
     (replace-regexp-in-string "<pre class=\"src src-\\([^\"]*?\\)\">"
                               "<pre>\n<code class=\"\\1\">\n" src))))

(add-to-list 'org-export-filter-src-block-functions
             'rasmus/org-html-wrap-blocks-in-code)

(setq org-html-htmlize-output-type nil)
```

Comment: Why did I get `htmlize-buffer-1: Symbol's function definition is void: nil`?

Comment: Maybe you haven't installed `htmlize.el`, which generates the fontification in the default `ox-html.el` setup.  If so don't say `(setq org-html-htmlize-output-type nil)`.  If it is the case that `(setq org-html-htmlize-output-type nil)` breaks the exporter when `htmlize.el` is not installed, please report it as a bug on the mailing list.

Comment: I exported my blog with org-page, and no error was triggered, it actually works! So, I don't know what went wrong the first time.

Comment: The magic pixies inside the cables!  They do this kind of stuff.  It is known!

Comment: the source code blocks include the programming language of the code, How do I access that information?

Comment: It's `\\1` in `"<pre class=\"src src-\\([^\"]*?\\)\">"`.  Is that what you mean?  IOW in accordance with the docstring, you should get something like `<pre><code class="LANG">.</code></pre>` from `#+begin_src LANG\n.\n#+end_src`.